# ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64.rpm error: Failed dependencies

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I tried installing ImageMagick. But getting following error:

I downloaded following:
wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/linux/CentOS/x86_64/ImageMagick-7.0.7-0.x86_64.rpm

wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/linux/CentOS/x86_64/ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64.rpm

```
[root@server ~]# rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libICE.so.6()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        libSM.so.6()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        libXext.so.6()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        libXt.so.6()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        libcairo.so.2()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        libfftw3.so.3()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        libgs.so.9()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        liblcms2.so.2()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        libltdl.so.7()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        libpango-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        libpangocairo-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
        libwmflite-0.2.so.7()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.0.7-0.x86_64
```

My server configurations:

```
[root@server ~]# php -v 
PHP 7.0.22 (cli) (built: Aug 7 2017 16:18:27) ( NTS ) 

[root@server ~]# nginx -v 
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2
```

OS: CentOS 7.3.1611 (Core)

Can someone help in getting these dependencies resolved?

Comment: Should be able to to use `yum` to install the missing dependencies. You'll need ghostscript, X, cairo, pango, lcms, fftw, and wmflite.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same issue issue. Install the following"

- `libICE`
- `libSM`
- `libXext`
- `cairo`
- `fftw3`

Uninstall the preinstalled Ghostscript i86 and Install the 64 bit version:

`yum install ghostscript`

`yum install lcms2`

`yum install libwmf-lite`

After installing the above dependencies you should see the Convert magic